# Operation not permitted on linux-rt

Tags: embedded, python-install, linux-rt

I need to install python 3.9 on an embedded device so I used USB drive to not consume much storage space on the board. Yet, whenever I start installing using`make install`

I get this error :
[image]

This is the content of the installation Folder after starting the installation.

[image]

How can I change the permessions so I won't have that error again?

Comment: The operation that is not permitted is just the `ln` command to create a symbolic link from `libpython3.9.so.1.0` to `libpython3.9.so`, so there was probably no need to post _all_ of that output - just the command that failed and the error message.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. do you have any idea how can I resolve this?